# number of search results when using twitter ruby gem

Tags: ruby, twitter

The code below returns 15 entries, no matter how big or small `:count` is. Why? How can I control the number of results?

```
Twitter.search("#ruby -rt", :lang => "ja", :count => 1).results
```

I am using twitter gem version 3.7.0.

Comment: Using your exact line of code, `puts Twitter.search("#ruby -rt", :lang => "ja", :count => 1).results.size`. Can you post your gem version and how you're getting 15 results to appear?

Comment: I have updated my question. version 3.7.0. results.size returns 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get this working in the `3.x.x` versions of the Gem. Updating to `>= 4.0.0` seems add the functionality you require. I think the `:count` option may not have been present.